# How to populate a comboBox with a return value?

Tags: c#, tfs

I have methods that return value/s to the main class. Now, how can I populate a comboBox in the main class using a return value?

```
public string MapWorkspace(string path)
{
    try
    {
        versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        Workspace[] retVal = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(null, "username", "computername");
        foreach (Workspace w in retVal)
        {
            return w.Name;
        }
        //var workspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace(path);  
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Write("Failed to map workspace! Exeption: " + exception.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}

public MainForm()
{
            tfs.MapWorkspace(path);
}
```

Comment: return `IEnumerable<string>` loop through it and populate

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to return more than 1 value, so in that case you want a return type of `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public IEnumerable<string> MapWorkspace(string path)
{
    try
    {
        versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        Workspace[] retVal = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(null, "username", "computername");
        foreach (Workspace w in retVal)
        {
            yield return w.Name;
        }
        //var workspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace(path);  
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Write("Failed to map workspace! Exeption: " + exception.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and depending of you UI framework you can populate your `ComboBox` using the same method

**Winforms:**

```
foreach(var item in MapWorkspace("mypath"))
{
   combobox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Wpf:**

```
MyItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(MapWorkspace("mypath"));
```

*where MyItems is a collection bound to the combobox*

Comment: I tried your solution, it works fine with populating the comboBox, thanks. But it seems that my versionControl becomes null when I use it in another method which maps the chosen workspace.Name from the comboBox.